# What is the purpose of having coroutine-specific functions?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, mockk

We can't use `every` and `verify` with coroutines because they don't take `suspend` functions as parameters. We have to use `coEvery` and `coVerify` instead.

But why can't we use `coEvery` and `coVerify` with non-suspend functions? Why can't `every` accept suspend functions (other than because it doesn't have the "suspend" keyword in its parameter list)?

My thinking is that if we could use `coEvery` with non-suspend functions, surely there would be no need to have separate functions, and just rename `coEvery` to `every`. But there must be something I'm missing in my understanding.

Comment: Maybe backwards compatibility reasons, `coEvery` probably arrived after `every`

Comment: @Joffrey good point. Would that be binary compatibility or source compatibility too? I would have thought that changing the parameter to `suspend` wouldn't require any code change for its users.

Comment: I don't think binary compatibility would be that important for test code (because it's unlikely to run tests without recompiling them with the new test library). As for source compatibility, indeed it's unlikely users would have to change anything. However, there may be additional machinery for coroutines that could make the behaviour of `every` and `coEvery` different (I'm just speculating of course)